# ! Package keyval Error: langjapanese undefined

Tags: biblatex

I'm completely new to LaTeX. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 (r.c29723a).
When I launch TeXworks and try to compile https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/Russian-Phd-LaTeX-Dissertation-Template/blob/master/Dissertation/dissertation.tex,
I receive the following error:

```
...
(C:\Tools\MiKTeX\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\russian.lbx
! Package keyval Error: langjapanese undefined.
```

By clicking on the error message I jump to the closing brace of "\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%" in "russian.lbx", but this "key-value table" does have a "langjapanese" entry in it:

```
langjapanese   = {{японский}{яп\adddot}},
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: As you don't know latex it is really not a good idea to use such a large template. Do you really think many people want to wade through all this files to find out what the template is doing every time you have a problem with it?

Comment: Can you bring the template down to a minimal code that produces the error?

Comment: That is exactly the error: `langjapanese=` is there but it has not been defined.

Answer (score 6):

This problem has been resolved in `biblatex` 3.2.

---

This is a tiny bug (more of a buglet, really) in the current release of `biblatex`. As far as I can tell it only occurs with `russian.lbx` because [two new strings were added](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/341), but it was neglected to declare said strings beforehand. The bug has been fixed in [`9ff117c`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/9ff117c7f179ee906acfe61c2466633321ff1b47) and [`cc2c322`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/cc2c3226fdb8d1d13338f6211b9aeae78e680c9c), the update, however, has not yet made it to CTAN I believe. A pre-release version with the fix is already available on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/).

Until the fixed version is uploaded

```
\NewBibliographyString{langjapanese}
\NewBibliographyString{fromjapanese}
```

should suffice as work-around.

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[russian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{langjapanese}
\NewBibliographyString{fromjapanese}
\begin{document}
\cite[9]{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

runs just fine

Comment: It is fixed in biblatex 3.2 which is in the development folder on Sourceforge. This requires biber 2.3 which is also on Sourceforge now.