# Biblatex and Polyglossia error after TeX Live update

Tags: biblatex, luatex, texlive, polyglossia

I've just updated TeX Live distribution (from `2015.37233` to `2015.38831`), and now I encounter error whenever `biblatex` package is loaded provided that default language is Russian. Here's the minimal non-working example (LuaLaTeX build):

```
\documentclass[final,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{libertine}

\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian} 

\usepackage{biblatex}  % compiles if commented out

\begin{document}

    Проверка.

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
russian.lbx: line  506: Package xkeyval Error: `fromjapanese' undefined in families `blx@lbx'. }
```

Here's the relevant place in `russian.lbx`:

```
...
505  annotation       = {{аннотация}{аннот\adddot}},
506 }
507 
508 \protected\gdef\lbx@ru@mkbibdatemonth#1{%
...
```

Should this be considered a bug?

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277314/package-keyval-error-langjapanese-undefined) your problem? (Look at the answer before replying…)

Comment: @MickG does that mean that the update is regressive? everything worked fine before (the fix in that answer works)

Comment: I have no idea :). Never used `russian.lbx` nor `LuaTeX`, so to get an answer to your comment you will have to wait for someone else.

Comment: This is the polyglossia manifestation of [! Package keyval Error: langjapanese undefined](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277314/35864). Funnily enough, the error message here is slightly more detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fromjapanese` and `langjapanese` keys are missing from the list in `biblatex2.sty`. Add them, I think the issue will be fixed soon.

```
\documentclass[final,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{libertine}

\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{biblatex}  % compiles if commented out

\makeatletter
\define@key{blx@lbx}{fromjapanese}{\blx@defstring{fromjapanese}{#1}}
\define@key{blx@lbx}{langjapanese}{\blx@defstring{langjapanese}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    Проверка.

\end{document}
```